# Combine percentage and count in histogram in plotly express python

Tags: python, graphics, plotly, histogram, plotly-express

On this case is different than all of the questions checked before, cause we are counting by row instead using the columns values or something like that.

The request here is to create a visualization where we can see the percentage of the rows related to one range of values and the count of rows, to identify percentage and count properly.

I´ll give a MRWE with the code that i tried to, it is needed to add the count total of data that is in that percentage bar.

```
import plotly.express as px
from matplotlib.ticker import PercentFormatter
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

df = sns.load_dataset('titanic')

fig = px.histogram(df, 
                   x="age", 
                   color="alive",
                   title="Num. of inspections depending velocity average and if it has or not an incident ", 
                   labels={'hayIncidente': 'Some incident?'},
                   barnorm = "percent",
                   category_orders={'index': [1,0]},
                      text_auto= '.2f').update_layout(
    yaxis_title="Percentage", 
    xaxis_title="ages"
)

fig.update_traces(marker_line_width=1,
                  marker_line_color="white")


fig.show()
```

I show a photo of the visualization that is created, but with some red numbers added to the bars where i would like to add the counts, another interesting way is to add (count/percentage)

[image: Visualization added]

Maybe the problem here is the library i am using and with another library and using other attributes can be possible.